# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I tried to load a image inside table view cells image view from a NSMutableArray. But I get warning 
***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.***

I tried many solutions posted in this site. But it is not working for me.

This is my code :

```
recipe1.numbers1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"], nil];
```

This is how i access those images:

```
cell1.numbersImageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipe.numbers1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: set nil to recipe1.numbers1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], ...,nil];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is the way you are accessing the image from the array, you already store an `UIImage` object there, there is no need (and is an error) to call `imageNamed:`, change the line to:

```
cell1.numbersImageview1.image = [recipe.numbers1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**EDIT**

In your code you are adding the access to the elements of the array as another object, try changing the whole code to this:

```
recipe1.numbers1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], 
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"], 
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"], 
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"], 
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"], nil];


cell1.numbersImageview1.image = [recipe.numbers1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: sorry,i cannot find any differce between mine and your code..this is the same one from which i am geting warning..

Comment: no, it is not, I'm closing the array declaration and I'm assigning the image property in a different way, maybe the problem is that in your question you post the badly

Comment: have you tried changing the line of code that is common in both of my answer?, if you take a look is the same solution that everybody give you, if the problem still remains then it is in other place

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong change this line :

```
cell1.numbersImageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipe.numbers1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];nil];
```

TO

```
cell1.numbersImageview1.image = [recipe1.numbers1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you try this one also once.

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   recipe1.numbers1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png",@"4.png",@"5.png",@"6.png",@"7.png",@"8.png",@"9.png",@"10.png"];
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
      ....................
      ....................

NSString *imagename=[recipe1.numbers1 objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
cell1.numbersImageview1.image =[UIImage imageNamed:imagename];
}
```